# Unable to create CloudFormation Stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Why is this error coming up:

> Confirming Stack pre-requisites Stack dependency missing - StandardTopics Stack does not exist!

Comment: Could you post the cloudformation template that you created? The error is self explanatory if that's all you are providing.

Comment: Run: "example-create-linuxwebserver-stack -E Production -T small -V 4.0.0 -i "? [Y/n/q]
Confirming Stack pre-requisites
Stack dependency missing - StandardTopics Stack does not exist!

Run: "example-create-linuxwebserver-stack -E Development -T small -V 1.0.0 -m -i "? [Y/n/q]
Confirming Stack pre-requisites
Stack dependency missing - StandardTopics Stack does not exist!'

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that the stack imports information from another stack (called `StandardTopics`). Therefore, it needs the `StandardTopics` stack to exist before this new stack can be built.

Look for `Fn::ImportValue` references in the stack you are trying to deploy. It will contain references to `StandardTopics`.